# Modify a HTML5 page without a server side page

Tags: html, save, synchronize

I have a editable html5 page and I store new elements in localStorage.
I want to synchronize my page with the server.
I want to know if I can do it without a server side script or if there is some tips to do something like this in a good way.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pull information from the server quite easily using jQuery and then just put it on Local Storage but, if you want to upload local information to the server there is no way around, you **have to** use some kind of script, tough it's not that difficult, there are many languages (PHP, C#, Python...) and tools you can use.

Keep in mind that when you upload information to the server you have to *sanitize* it **very important** security measure.

Basically, the way to go is:

- Post the information to the server (using AJAX or a HTML form, either way will do)
- Use some server-side script to capture the variables posted.
- **Sanitize** your data (check format, discard non-valid characters, etc)
- Store it on database (**Do not**, ever, concatenate your data with a SQL query ok? that can make you vulnerable to a SQL injection attack), compute something or do stuff.
- Return some status to the client (some confirmation maybe?)
- You may want to take that confirmation and show a message to the user ("Your info was saved properly" or something like that)

Comment: My problem here that I don't know which language that the server support ? I'm searching for something which works with all type of server.(Php, Java ...)

Comment: PHP is universal, its the P in WAMP and LAMP (Linux/Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP).

Comment: PHP is a safe option, it's supported on almost any web-server and it's easy to learn. Java is widely supported but you might don't want to mess with it if you are starting (need to do more things manually). ASP.net only works on Windows servers. Python is becoming more popular, but not so much so I would go with PHP

Comment: Take a look at a tutorial like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp), there are thousands on the web for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

is a javascript timer not sufficient for this manner? or jQuery?

The question really should be more of a problem than a question. If you're updating based on a server's variables then you could use AJAX i believe but if its like increment said variable every X seconds I would focus on using a javascript timer.